# Difference between jQuery Validation and Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, nuget-package

What's the difference between the nugget packages **Jquery Validation** and **Microsoft Jquery Unobtrusive** when using them for validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery Validation** is just a javascript plugin used by Microsoft through its custom javascript named **Microsoft jQuery Unobstrusive** plugin to make ASP.Net MVC validation on client side a quiet simple.

**jQuery Validation** by definition (source https://jqueryvalidation.org/) :

> This jQuery plugin makes simple clientside form validation easy,
>   whilst still offering plenty of customization options. It makes a good
>   choice if you’re building something new from scratch, but also when
>   you’re trying to integrate something into an existing application with
>   lots of existing markup. The plugin comes bundled with a useful set of
>   validation methods, including URL and email validation, while
>   providing an API to write your own methods.

**Microsoft jQuery Unobstrusive** need and works upon **jQuery Validation**. When you're using ASP.Net Validation like decorating your model with some data annotations attributes (`Required`, `EmailAddress`, etc), ASP.Net MVC generates some `data-*` attribute on fields that are related to your model. **Microsoft jQuery Unobstrusive** use those `data-*` and make your developer life easy so you don't need to code all thoses things describe in the **[jQuery Validation vidéo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaxUV3Ib4vM)**. That is why the **Unobstrusive** word is on **Microsoft jQuery Unobstrusive**. Go to this link to learn more about **[Unobstrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)**